# read text file from another text file Matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi
Is it possible to open and read text file from another one. For example
"file1.txt" contain 2 columns and the data are:
1, "file4.txt"
2, "file5.txt"
3, "file6.txt"

and I want to display column 2 from file4,5 and 6

Any idea? and how to implement it
Thanks guys

Comment: Interceptor361 is correct. The question is not clear. In Matlab you can open any file, and you can extract any column, so no problem. Why don't you show your code and where you have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first read the contents of 'file1.txt' like this

```
fid = fopen('file1.txt'); 
fileContents = textscan(fid,'%d %q','Delimiter',',');
```

And then iterate over the second column (the file names) of the file's content

```
fileNames = fileContents{2};
for i = 1:length(fileNames)
    % filenames{i} will be 'file4.txt', 'file5.txt', 'file6.txt' respectively in
    % each iteration
    fid2 = fopen(fileNames{i});
         %%%%% put code to read second column here %%%%
    fclose(fid2);
end
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have too low reputation to comment hence answering..
I think you question is you have a text file **file1.txt** and in that file you have data of file4 and file5 right? Either you have link of the file4.txt or you have its data.. In both cases you need to filter that part(either file path to file4 or its data) and then store its content in an array so you can modify according to your needs later.. Please be more specific about your problem while questioning..